# OpenGL Texture override material color

Tags: opengl, shader, fragment-shader

I want to render a scene and blend the material color with the texture. i am using programmable pipeline and GLSL, when the function texture() is called, all the portion of the meshes wish dont have texture become transparent. (even if i dont use the vec4 in the final fragColor)

look in the screeshots below, in the first image i have only the material color, in the second the applied texture, but the faces with only material color become transparent..

in my fragment shader, i have something like that:

```
vec4 tex = texture(texsampl,fTexCoord);
fFragColor = ambient + (diffuse*tex)  + specular;
```

Comment: cant post images, reputation below 10... =(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> only material color become transparent.

Well, you're adding the values, that's what to be expected. You should instead use some blending function like `mix` (= `s*a + d*(1-a)` where s and d are material and texture and a is some blending factor) or `slerp`.

Comment: the diffuse, specular and ambinet component is already blended to work as a sum.

i am using ATI graphic card. 
about a minute ago i tested on nvidia and then everything worked fine... so i think its a bug with ATI/AMD opengl driver...

Comment: @bruchuck: possible, but hard to tell without more source code.